# Java - enum where one variable can be multi-valued

Tags: java, enums

I have an enum like below. Until recently, all variables were single-valued. However, now TYPE4 can have one of three acceptable values. I was hoping to simply modify this enum to accommodate for TYPE4, but thinking perhaps having only one type that is multi-valued means I need to use an object for mapping rather than an enum. I would be grateful for any insights. Thank you.

```
public enum Record {
    TYPE1("TYPE1"),
    TYPE2("TYPE2"),
    TYPE3("TYPE3"),
    TYPE4_MULTI(TYPE_A or TYPE_B or TYPE_C); 

    private final String value;
    public static final Map<Record, String> enumMap = new EnumMap<Record, String>(
        Record.class);

    static {
        for (Record e : Record.values())
            enumMap.put(e, e.getValue());
    }

    Record(String value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    public String getValue() {
        return value;
    }
}
```

Operationally, I use this enum in a factory class to determine which of 4 types of subclasses I should instantiate. I do this by have each of the subclasses know its own type like this:

```
@Override
public String getType() {
    return Record.TYPE1.getValue();
}
```

,and then the factory class pre-builds a set of the subclasses like this:

```
@Component
public class RecordProcessorFactory {

    @Autowired
    public RecordProcessorFactory(List<RecordProcessor> processors) {
        for (RecordProcessor recordProcessor : processors) {
            processorCache.put(recordProcessor.getType(), recordProcessor);
        }
    }

    private static final Map<String, RecordProcessor> processorCache = new HashMap<String, RecordProcessor>();

    public RecordProcessor getSyncProcessor(String type) {
        RecordProcessor service = processorCache.get(type);
        if(service == null) throw new RuntimeException("Unknown service type: " + type);
        return service;
    }
}
```

Comment: question: what is the function of `enumMap`? (`enumMap.get(rec)` is basically the same result as `rec.getValue()` [ignoring the `rec==null`] case) || If you need multi-values, then maybe `value` should be a `List`, or some other Collection.

Comment: What is the datatype of TYPE_A, TYPE_B and TYPE_C? Are they Strings?

Comment: I would suggest hiding `enumMap` and providing just a method like `static Record map(String)` that does the lookup. You wouldn't want to allow tampering with the map from the outside.

Comment: What you're asking doesn't make sense.. When you have a variable of type `Record`, what do you want to assign it to when it's "TYPE4_MULTI"? It can't be of 3 types at the same time, right? Otherwise it's a one-to-many relationship and you'd have to store a collection of `Record`s

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a String array to store multiple values, note that your logic may change with `enumMap` that way.

```java
public enum Record {
    TYPE1("TYPE1"),
    TYPE2("TYPE2"),
    TYPE3("TYPE3"),
    TYPE4_MULTI("TYPE_A", "TYPE_B", "TYPE_C");

    private final String[] values;
    public static final Map<Record, String[]> enumMap = new EnumMap<Record, String[]>(Record.class);

    static {
        for (Record e : Record.values())
            enumMap.put(e, e.getValues());
    }


    Record(String... values) {
        this.values = values;
    }

    public String[] getValues() {
        return values;
    }
}
```

In case you need to get the `Enum` from a `String` value, you could add this static method:

```java
public static Optional<Record> optionalValueOf(final String value) {
    for (Record record : values()) {
        for (String recordValue : record.values) {
            if (null == value && null == recordValue || value.equals(recordValue)) {
                return Optional.of(record);
            }
        }
    }
    return Optional.empty();
}
```

Comment: but `enumMap` is a Map **from** Record **to** String - `optionalValueOf` is more like the reverse (from String to Record, which is reasonable)... (reason why I asked what is the intended function of `enumMap` )

Comment: You're right, I modify my answer, thanks.

Comment: @Alexis, I am unfamiliar with "String...". What is this? When was this introduced to java? Thanks

Comment: @Timothy Clotworthy This is called [varargs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/language/varargs.html), it is similar to `String[]` but does not require an array parameter, you can pass any number of `String` parameters. So instead of writing `function(new String[] {"foo", "bar"})` you can directly write `function("foo", "bar")`.

Comment: @Alexis, ok, thanks for clarification. So, your solution acommodates the situation where I simply need to know whether a value (yes a String) presented is within the total values array and thus I can use your optionalValueOf method. However, the 4 types are used in a factory class to determine which of  4 subclasses I should instantiate, and I think your solution as presented prevents me from saying if String is TYPE_A or TYPE_B or TYPE_C, instatiate TYPE4_MULTI subclass. Perhaps another static public method could be added to perform this task? I'll update post to clarify.

Comment: `optionalValueOf("TYPE_A")`, `optionalValueOf("TYPE_B")` and `optionalValueOf("TYPE_C")` will all return an `Optional` of `TYPE4_MULTI`. I don't get why you couldn't use it in your factory.

Comment: @Alexis, I updated my post with the factory information

Comment: Not sure if I understood properly, but you could change `processorCache` from `Map<String, RecordProcessor>` to `Map<Record, RecordProcessor>` and replace `processorCache.get(type)` by `processorCache.get(Record.optionalValueOf(type).orElse(null))`.

Comment: @Alexis, I think that will address the getSyncProcessor() method, but still not sure what to do about the constructor for RecordProcessorFactory. Thanks so much for all your help so far!

Comment: You could achieve the same, such as `processorCache.put(Record.optionalValueOf(recordProcessor.getType()).orElseThrow(), recordProcessor)`.

Comment: @Alexis, thanks for all your help! All good thanks to you. I just had to tweak a couple of things:    
    public Record getType() {
        return Record.TYPE;  , and:  for (RecordProcessor recordProcessor : processors) {
            processorCache.put(recordProcessor.getType(), recordProcessor);
        }

Answer (score 0):

I think it's better to encapsulate values in the enum. It should be immutable (array is not immutable data storage).

```java
@lombok.Getter
public enum Record {
    TYPE1("TYPE1"),
    TYPE2("TYPE2"),
    TYPE3("TYPE3"),
    TYPE4_MULTI("TYPE_A", "TYPE_B", "TYPE_C");

    // immutable list
    private final List<String> values;

    Record(String... values) {
        this.values = Arrays.stream(values)
                            .collect(Collectors.toList());
    }

}
```

***P.S.** `Map<Record, String> enumMap` I think is useless, because you have a `Record` already and all you need just call `record.getValues()` instead of `Record.enumMaps.get(record)`. Also, this is breakes OOP encapsulation.*